# Ordinary Differential Equation with variable coffiecient

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am studying ODE. I got stuck in following question which was given in my text book exercise.

> Find solution of D.E. $y''+ye^x=0$

I can't recognize the type. As $y'$ term is not there so I can't make this variable coefficient to constant coefficient problem. So please help me.

Comment: We know for any $x$ we have a ordinary point, so by Fuchs Theorem, we know all the solutions have a power series solution. So expand $y,y’,e^x$ as a power series and solve for the coefficients to get the answer. It’ll be in terms of special functions known as the Bessel functions. (I don’t think it’s possible to convert this problem into a constant coefficient problem)

Comment: For large $x\gg1$ you get via WKB approximation $y(x)\sim e^{-x/4}(A\cos(2e^{x/2})+B\sin(2e^{x/2}))$. So you could try to compute the equation for $y(x)=f(2e^{x/2})$ and compare that to the equations for special functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a second-order *linear* ordinary differential equation (ODE) here.

This particular ODE can be transformed to Bessel's differential equation by the definition of a new independent variable $z := 2 e^{x/2}$.

edit: Basically the same as LutzL's suggestion.